# how to put asp textbox into div in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have some asp.net textbox (`<asp:TextBox></asp:TextBox>`) and i want when click in button put this textbox into div  such as this output(`<div><asp:TextBox></asp:TextBox></div>`)

i try do it with wrap method,but when click in the button div is created and textbox put this but textbox dosent work and i could not write something to the textbox.

thank you for you'r help

**i know that asp is server side , my asp control is available in my page and just i want put this into div**

Comment: asp.net controls need to be added server-side. You can't create asp.net controls with javascript. Edit- Unless you already have the controls on the page and you just want to move them, in which case that might be possible, but we probably need to see your code.

Comment: asp.net doesn't works that way, they are SERVER CONTROLS and need server to process them.

Comment: the place where you are writing this jquery code, is it a server side script ?

Comment: @ManojPurohit  i know that asp is server side , my asp control is available in my page
and just i want put this into div

Comment: it's difficult from your question to assess what you are trying to do.. code speaks thousand words, if you can share it that'd be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might have the HTML as `textarea`. So try to add a parent to that textarea instead of adding the textarea to a div. Like this

```
$('textarea').wrap('<div></div>');
```

As already mentioned, you cannot add the controls using JS or any of its library, they are server-side. If you just want to move it to be a child of some other particular element. Use `.wrap()` to enclose it inside a parent element.

http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/grwYX/1/

You can try the fiddle to see how a textarea is moved to a new parent. Is editable, is clickable and having a new parent.